# java playframework how can I display database results in the view

Tags: java, jdbc, playframework

I am new to the playframework 2.38 and JDBC but I have successfully connected to MySQL and can do inserts,however I do not know how to display records to the browser using jdbc or the play framework. I do know that I am close this is my Controller..

```
 public static Result getlocation()
{
try {

    Connection conn = DB.getConnection();
    ResultSet rs;
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select city from zips where city=? limit 1");
    ps.setString(1,"Dallas");
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next() ) {
        rs.getString("city");
    }

    conn.close();
    return ok(rs.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
}


return ok();
  }
```

All I am trying to do is get a record from MySQL and pass it to the view but I get this error
**com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@29ffd4fa**
My view is this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Play project get database record </title>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

What do I need to put in the view to show my database record? All the information I see online is about play-scala and not much about Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get is not an error - this is just the `toString`-representation of your result set - this is what you do when you write this line `rs.toString()`.

Let's say you found your city with the query and now you are here:

```
rs.getString("city");
```

You can just use this as a **parameter for the view** - you 'feed' the view with data and the view displays this data. So you can change it like:

```
String myCity = rs.getString("city");
return ok(cityTemplate.render(myCity));
```

Now, your view (which is named `cityTemplate.scala.html`) has to be able to 'consume' the parameters that you are feeding it with, so it will go like this:

```
@(city: String)
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Play project get database record </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Your city is @city</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pay attention to the first row with `@(city: String)` - this is how you say "my view is going to accept one parameter, of type `String`, with the name `city`. Then you can use this parameter by prepending a `@`  to it. You can learn more about the templates in Play Framework here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTemplates

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate the help and that solved it.